# Has anyone configured Galleon or TezBox with a local node?

Tags: node, wallets

I am having some troubles connecting either one of these two wallets to a local node on the same machine. The correct ports are listening (netstat -tulpn).    The setup of TLS looks good, for example I get the correct response when poking the tezos node 
with:

```
./tezos-client -port 1234 -S get balance for xyz
```

In config.json I tried different flavors of  "listen-addr" (both in "rpc" and "p2p"), 127.0.0.1, localhost,
::1, 0.0.0.0 + port numbers, nothing seems to work.

Perhaps it is the self-signed TLS certificate or the location of the files,
any idea?

Comment: Please post the answer as an answer instead of inside your question! It will help mods understand that the question has actually been answered and you can also mark it as such which will help mods. Thanks

Comment: apologies for the confusion. I agree the answer should have been posted as a comment. This is what I wanted to do until I read the following text in the comment box:        "Use comments to reply to other users or notify them of changes. If you are adding
new information, edit your post instead of commenting."

Comment: Sorry you still got it wrong. Your should please post the answer as an “ANSWER”, not as a comment and not in the question itself. Please let me know if something is not clear in what i am saying.

Answer (score 2):

**SOLUTION** (for TezBox web version)

Not as intuitive as one can imagine. The following has been done on a machine with Fedora OS running a Tezos node.
First as a user create a certificate and a key:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout server.key -new -out server.crt -subj /CN=localhost -reqexts SAN -extensions SAN -config <(cat /etc/pki/tls/openssl.cnf <(printf '[SAN]\nsubjectAltName=DNS:localhost,DNS:127.0.0.1,IP:127.0.0.1')) -sha256 -days 3650
```

Install node.js as root:

```
dnf install nodejs
```

(the above command will install also npm (js package manager))
install local-web-server, as root:

```
 npm install -g local-web-server
```

run local-web-server as a user:

```
  ws --https --hostname 127.0.0.1 --key /home/<user>/server.key --cert /home/<user>/server.crt --rewrite '/chains/* ->http://localhost:8732/chains/$1' -v
```

the command assumes that the certificate and the key are in /home/<*user>*, the Tezos RPC port is 8732, the default port for 127.0.0.1 is 8000 (the flag -v is for verbose output).

Use Chrome to connect to https://127.0.0.1:8000 and click on proceed to 127.0.0.1 (unsafe)
then type the f12 key and follow "view certificate" -> "details" -> "export" and save the certificate as PKCS #7 Certificates (e.g. output name localhost).
Make sure that nss-tools is installed (for other linux distros it is called libnss3-tools).
From the location where the localhost file has been saved, as a user type:

```
  certutil -d sql:/home/max/.pki/nssdb -A -t "P,," -n localhost -i localhost
```

Restart Chrome, now connecting to https://127.0.0.1:8000 should not show any warning.

Go to https://wallet.tezbox.com and open an existing/new wallet then go to setting (upper right rod) and replace https://rpc.tezrpc.me with https://127.0.0.1:8000

---

[addendum 04/10/19] It also works with Opera browser. Instead of using F12 to enter the developers mode, type Ctrl+Shift+I then go to security -> view certificate, the rest is the same. Green light for TezBox connected to a local node using Opera.